# JSON RPC calls for Armory wallet

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, armory

I'm trying to access an armory wallet via RPCs. For instance using the procedure `listreceivedbyaddress` should ideally return all of the addresses in my Armory wallet. However, when I run this from my shell I get

$ bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress

[
]

I definitely have addresses inside of my wallet, so I must have some configuration stuff wrong. I let armory start `bitcoind` on its own, and then I start making calls from `bitcoin-cli`. Is this the wrong way to use this? I feel like I am missing an authentication step.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. Are you using armory's wallet, or bitcoind's wallet?

Comment: I want to be querying an Armory wallet. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: I'm not certain there is a way to query armory over RPC.

Comment: Can you upvote for visibility?